# Python program only works with single digit numbers

Tags: python

I made a simple program to find the larger number.  It works great, but it has issues when you start putting two digits into the input.

```
input_num1 = input("Enter The First Number: ") 
input_num2 = input("Enter The Second Number: ")

list = []

list.append(input_num1)
list.append(input_num2)

if input_num1 == input_num2:
  print ("These numbers are equal")
else:
  print(max(list))
```

I was wondering if someone could tel me why this is the case.

Comment: `input()` returns *strings*.  Strings are compared character-by-character, so `10` is less than `2`, for example.  Use `int()` to turn your values into actual numbers.

Comment: as @jasonharper said convert input to integer: `int(input("Enter The First Number: "))`